# Twitter 1.1 image upload issue using Abraham Williams sdk in php

Tags: php, twitter

I am new for posting images in twitter account using php sdk.

I have tried but not got solution yet.

My code is

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($twitter_key, $twitter_secret, $token, $secret);

$fileContent = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
$base64   = base64_encode($fileContent);
$fileContent = ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);

 $connection->post("https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", array("media_data" =>$fileContent));
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: it is giving an error (
    [request] => /1.1/media/upload.json
    [error] => media type unrecognized.
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution of my question which help me to resolve upload image.

```
$url = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json';
$method = 'POST';
$parameters = array('media' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), );
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($connection->consumer, $connection->
token, $method, $url, $parameters);
$request->sign_request($connection->sha1_method, $connection->consumer, $connection->
token);

$response = $connection->http($request->get_normalized_http_url(), $method, $request->
to_postdata());
if ($connection->format === 'json' && $connection->decode_json)
{
    $response = json_decode($response);
    $mediaId[] = $response->media_id_string;
}
```

Comment: My example below is the method officially supported by TwitterOAuth, the way you are doing it is using private endpoints that are likely going to change in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment will update as per your suggested code and provided link.

Comment: I keep getting '''Class 'OAuthRequest' not found''' when I do this method.

Answer (score 2):

You're not following the [TwitterOAuth documentation](https://twitteroauth.com/) for uploading media.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$media1 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/path/to/file/kitten1.jpg']);
$media2 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/path/to/file/kitten2.jpg']);
$parameters = [
    'status' => 'Meow Meow Meow',
    'media_ids' => implode(',', array($media1->media_id_string, $media2->media_id_string)),
];
$result = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply will check with your reference url